# Pass email to ResendEmailConfirmation model/view - Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm trying to pass the user's email to Identity's ResendEmailConfirmation.cshtml class from the register page, so that it is displayed on view in the Email Input box.

**Register Page - The link to redirect the user to the Resend Email Confirmation page**

```
<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/resendemailconfirmation" asp-route-email="@Model.Input.Email" class="resend-confirm-email-submit">Resend confirmation email</a>
```

**ResendEmailConfirmation.cshtml - Relevant Parts**

```
        public ResendEmailConfirmationModel(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet(string email)
        {
            // My attempt
            InputModel inputModel = new InputModel();
            inputModel.Email = email;
        }
```

**ResendEmailConfirmation View - Email Input Box**

```
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="register-heading-style"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Resend</button>*@
            <button type="submit" class="register-submit"><span>Resend</span></button>
        </form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this way to define Input in OnGet():

**Register.cshtml.cs** to get the email (You didn't show this part of code, so I directly define the value):

```
public void OnGet()
    {
        Input =new InputModel()   
        { 
            Email = "asd@asd.com"
        };
    }
```

Then **ResendEmailConfirmation.cshtml.cs** to show the email that passed from register page:

```
public void OnGet(string email)
    {
        Input = new InputModel()  //you get value from Input.Eamil in view, so you should define Input, not inputmodel
        {
            Email = email
        };            
    }
```

You do not have to change the razor view pages.

Result:

[image]